# Friendly SEO URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to know how to make SEO friendly URLs, say I have a URL in this format `http://www.domain.com/file.php?v1=a` ... Now I need users to use `http://www.domain.com/a` and this redirects to the previous ...

How can this be achieved?

And for say `http://www.domain.com/folder1` how can I force it to go to `http://www.domain.com/folder2` via .httaccess?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find a solution for both questions ...

1)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+).*$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

2)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1$ folder2 [PT,L]
```